# Turn dictionary into manageable code as a workaround to a bug

Tags: c#, dictionary

In my code I have this long dictionary:

```
static Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>> Translations = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>() {
    ["English"] = new Dictionary<string, string>() {
        ["date0"] = "Tuesday, 22nd January 2019",
        ["time0"] = "8:38 PM",
        ["date1"] = "Saturday, 14th September 2019",
        ["time1"] = "5:26 PM",
        ["date2"] = "Saturday, 28th March 2020",
        ["time2"] = "7:52 AM",
        ["date3"] = "Saturday, 28th March 2020",
        ["time3"] = "1:03 PM",
        ...
    }, 
    ["Italian"] = new Dictionary<string, string>() {
        ["date0"] = "Martedì, 22 gennaio 2019",
        ["time0"] = "20:38",
        ["date1"] = "Sabato, 14 settembre 2019",
        ["time1"] = "17:26",
        ["date2"] = "Sabato, 28 marzo 2020",
        ["time2"] = "7:52",
        ["date3"] = "Sabato, 28 marzo 2020",
        ["time3"] = "13:03",
        ...
    }
}
```

As a workaround to a Unity bug (https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/il2cpp-build-hangs-while-building-a-project-with-a-large-array-of-strings), I have to load data from an external file or encode it as a stream of bytes.

> You can then read the data into an array *(or a dictionary, in my case)* yourself and avoid the
> time/memory expended by the C++ compiler.

How do I accomplish this task?

Comment: What do you have so far? You could try serialize and deserialize into JSON or using Protobuf

Comment: Do you really need all these translations of times? Surely you can get the framework to do that on the fly and just store the times in a central format?

Comment: I have other translations afterwards that are not just about times but also dialogues.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't keep them all in resource files then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to read from an external JSON file and deserialize it to a dictionary using [JSON .NET](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeDictionary.htm)